# input box long text doesnt end, scrolls horizontally to reveal hidden text

Tags: html, css

So i have made column widths for my input text (which i am mandated by client to do so...)

```
    <td colspan="1" width="250">
             <input type="text" id="CUSTOMER_NAME" 
               name="APPLICATION.CUSTOMER_NAME" 
               value="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567891011" 
               size="30" 
               maxlength="30"/>
     </td>
```

At first look, it does seem like its truncated. Like below. But in actual fact once you double-click on the text, you can scroll horizontally to reveal the text further to the right

[image]
[image]

**Is there any way to prevent the horizontal scroll and have the text wrap to the second line for IE 7 *without using textarea*?**

Expected outcome:
[image]

Comment: IE7 can be a pain, must it be input box - or could you do a textarea (that can start as multiple lines or even be re-sized by user?)

Comment: @Andy yes it has to be IE7 without `textarea`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text boxes are single line only ([source](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#input-control-types)).  I would recommend using a `<textarea>` to try and solve your problem.

Comment: theres really no other way guys?

Comment: Sorry, I know it stinks. You could do something like what @Scott Selby said and increase the width when it is focused using JavaScript.

Comment: @bouncingHippo What kind of dimensions are you looking for when it comes to the initial and default size of the box?  You could start with something simple like: <textarea cols=25 rows=3></textarea>.  You can also look into JS functions that auto-resize your textarea  when you roll onto another line.  Some basics on textarea: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you want a second line, use a `<textarea>`.  Alternatively, try using the `width` CSS property as in `<input type="text" style="width: 100px;" />`

Comment: Did you try a larger value of width?  100px was just meant to be an example.  Either you need to use a textarea to do multiline, make the field wider, or make the text smaller.

Comment: yes it does affect the width of the field, but the text in that field can still be scrolled horizontally in IE 7

Comment: Make it wide enough so that the widest 30-character string you can put in there is narrower than the textbox...

Answer (score 0):

is it  an option to do something like on focus width: 100% , then blur back to what the client specified as their desired width?

Comment: maybe, can you suggest some code i can try out and see if the result is what theyre okay with